# Potentiometer motor system is not working

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, code-review, potentiometer

I am setting up a potentiometer system that includes a motor that is supposed to spin with the potentiometer changing the speed of the spin and a button to reverse it. I checked the coding and it is correct, the potentiometer, button, and motor are all functioning, but the system does not run. Can anyone propose any solutions to this issue?

```
int enablePin = 11;
int in1Pin = 10;
int in2Pin = 9;
int switchPin = 7;
int potPin = 0; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(in1Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enablePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}


void loop() {
  int speed = analogRead(potPin) / 4;
  Serial.println(speed);
  boolean reverse = digitalRead(switchPin);
  setMotor(speed, reverse);

}
void setMotor(int speed, boolean reverse)
{
  analogWrite(enablePin, speed);
  digitalWrite(in1Pin, ! reverse);
  digitalWrite(in2Pin, reverse);

}
```

[image: breadboard]

[image: reference board]

Comment: I think the problem is that your "code" is an image. You can't compile an image.

Comment: @Majenko if that is an issue, it is no longer an image... :D

Comment: It looks, in the first image, like you have edited the picture to wipe out the markings on the L239D. Maybe it's not an L239D and you're trolling us? I can't see anything immediately wrong at first glance...

Comment: Or maybe it's just that the JPEG compression is so high it's hard to make out details any more.

Comment: BTW you should really connect all the GND pins of the L239D.

Comment: @Majenko I have confirmed that the pins follow the diagram correctly and the controller is in fact an L293D.

Comment: @Majenko Could you clarify further on the GND pin statement, please? We are both somewhat new to Arduino and are following the diagram supplied to us. Is it wrong?

Comment: The L239D has four pins labelled GND. All four of them should be connected to the GND of the Arduino (through the GND rail of the breadboard of course). It shouldn't matter, and it's doubtful that it is causing your problem, but it's good practice.

Comment: Measure the voltage on pin D9, D10, and D11. Also, it looks like motor supply uses USB supply. That's bad idea, you can potentially damage the USB port. If you can, use an external supply.

Comment: Does it run, whem you introduce a `delay(100)` into the loop function? When the motor function is called too fast, the PWM signal will restart constantly